# swift if let statement with as?,but why use question mark?

Tags: swift, syntax

I can understand the statement, but as is good enough to cast any type, why followed by a question mark like:

```
if let foo = object as? String
```

It's really bugging me. Does it mean object is optional or the return value of the variable `foo` is an optional string type? Or it really means nothing just a language syntax? It must means something otherwise why is it there in the first-place? What does it mean? The question mark after word as in the `if let` statement.

I did search and can't find any.

i was confused course i know `object` is already an optional and be assigned to variable `foo` then `if let` unwrap it if it can unwrap,or jumped out the following statement.

so the `if let` unwrapping procedure is happening after `as?` type casting right? after `as?`casting a optional string from the example, then `if let` is unwrapping that not the optional object class assigned to the variable.

Comment: Weird, I found it right away when I searched: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23

Comment: Please read  [Swift Programming Language: Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) section *Downcasting*

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. i read and learned. please answer my last edited question in my post.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Your link is to a blog entry on `as!` and `as?` is only mentioned in an analogy. Did you maybe intended to link to a blog entry on `as?`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code:

```
if let foo = object as? String
```

breaks into two significant parts: `object as? String` and `if let`.

The first is a downcast which allows for *failure* by producing an optional type (`String?` here). From [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1): Typecasting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html):

> Use the conditional form of the type cast operator (`as?`) when you are not sure if the downcast will succeed. This form of the operator will always return an optional value, and the value will be `nil` if the downcast was not possible. This enables you to check for a successful downcast.

The second, `if let`, is an *optional binding* which unwraps an optional, the body of the `if let` is only executed if the optional value being unwrapped is not `nil` and with the bound variable being bound to the unwrapped value. See [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) in *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1): Basics*.

So your sense that something is happening *twice* here is correct. The `as?` cast may fail and produce a `nil` optional value, the `if let` will test that optional value for `nil`. We can only hope that the compiler handles the combination of `if let` and `as?` together and no unneccesary optionals are actually created and destroyed by the implementation.

HTH

Comment: hey thanks for not laughing in his face and by extension other newbies